# Group by and concatenate the columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have following dataframe.

```
  id1          id2          id3   lan term      
0 100000000006 100000023268 10000 en  Abnormal pain
1 100000000006 100000023268 10000 zh  jhkghdgh 
2 100000000006 100000023268 10000 cs  ghjdgfhgd 
3 100000000006 100000023268 10000 nl  jgfhgjhgfh
4 100000000006 100000023268 10000 fr  hgdhfghjgeh
5 100000000006 100000023269 10000 en  pain
6 100000000006 100000023269 10000 fr  hgdhfghjgehd
7 100000000006 100000023269 10000 nl  hgdhfghjgehdff
```

I would like to group by column id1, id2, id3 and concatenate the 'term' column values where lan is not 'en' and create a new column for this. The expected dataframe is:

```
  id1          id2          id3     term            synonyms
0 100000000006 100000023268 10000   Abnormal pain   jhkghdgh |ghjdgfhgd|jgfhgjhgfh|hgdhfghjgeh
3 100000000006 100000023269 10000   pain            hgdhfghjgehd|hgdhfghjgehdff
```

How can I achive this. I am using below code but without any filter on 'lan' column.

```
join_unique = lambda x: '|'.join(x.unique())
df_meddra_qtt = df_meddra.groupby(['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], as_index=False).agg(join_unique)
```

Comment: You can change the lambda to cover for filter and then use merge. Example, df_meddra_qtt = df_meddra.groupby(['id1', 'id2', 'id3']).agg({
    'term': lambda x: '|'.join(x[x.index != 0])
}).reset_index()

I'm updating with an answer which works for me. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Subset the columns you want before grouping.  You can use a custom aggregation function to keep the first term separate from the rest, then split it later.

```
def custom_agg(items):
    first = items[0]
    items_set = set(items)
    items_set.remove(first)
    return (first, '|'.join(items_set))

    
df_meddra_qtt = (
    df_meddra[['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'term']]
        .groupby(['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], as_index=False)
        .agg(custom_agg)
)

df_meddra_qtt['synonyms'] = df_meddra_qtt.term.str[1]
df_meddra_qtt['term'] = df_meddra_qtt.term.str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for filtering, group by and concatenate to get the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id1': [100000000006]*8,
'id2': [100000023268]*5 + [100000023269]*3,
'id3': [10000]*8,
'lan': ['en', 'zh', 'cs', 'nl', 'fr', 'en', 'fr', 'nl'],
'term': ['Abnormal pain', 'jhkghdgh', 'ghjdgfhgd', 'jgfhgjhgfh', 'hgdhfghjgeh',
         'pain', 'hgdhfghjgehd', 'hgdhfghjgehdff']})

# group the data and concatenate the terms
grouped = df.groupby(['id1', 'id2', 'id3'])\
        .agg({'term': lambda x: '|'.join(x[df['lan'] != 'en'])})\
        .reset_index()

# merge the original data with the grouped data
result = pd.merge(df[df['lan'] == 'en'], grouped, on=['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], how='left')
result = result[['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'term_x', 'term_y']]
result.columns = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'term', 'synonyms']
```

Output:

```
                    id1           id2            id3     term        synonyms
            0   100000000006    100000023268    10000 Abnormal pain  jhkghdgh|ghjdgfhgd|jgfhgjhgfh|hgdhfghjgeh
            1   100000000006    100000023269    10000   pain    hgdhfghjgehd|hgdhfghjgehdff
```

Comment: Your script is not working for the whole dataframe. I mean I have more rows with different 'id2' values. As the new rows starts, it concatenates even 'en' with other languages. I have added more rows for clarity

Comment: I've updated the code and it should work now as requested.